# Comparing 2 lists and managing inserts based on that in Dart

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, flutter-test

I have a case where I want to implement a feed solution. I have a GraphQL subscription where I get feed items from database realtime. I use Bloc/Cubit for simple state management.

```
    Future<void> updateFeed() async {

    emit(FeedLoading());
    List<Map<String, int>> _feed = [];

    Snapshot snapshot = await Server.server.testSubs();
    snapshot.listen((event) {});
    emit(FeedUpdate(_feed));
    emit(FeedLoaded());
  }
```

This is the function that I get list of updates from feed table. I have an animated list on feed page which returns widgets based on widget type.

```
 Widget listWidgetType(index) {
    switch (_feed[index].entries.first.key) {
      case "match":
        return Match(
          matchId: _feed[index]["match"],
        );
        break;
      case "transfer":
        return Transfer(username: _feed[index]["transfer"]);
        break;
      case "news":
        return News();
        break;
      default:
        return Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Text("Unknown Data"),
        );
    }
  }
```

Because I need to use this switch case I have to have a local list. So I update local list based on Cubit list and then add them to this AnimatedList.

```
SliverAnimatedList(
                key: _listKey,
                itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                  return FadeTransition(
                      opacity: animation.drive(Tween<double>(
                        begin: 0,
                        end: 1,
                      ).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc))),
                      child: listWidgetType(index));
                },
              );
```

My problem is I have to compare two lists based on item id and see if they exist. If they exist I skip adding part. This is fairly simple for last item. But lets say I removed an item from 10th of the list. I want to remove it from feed dynamically, in real time. So I need to compare the list each time, sort it based on itemCreated time stamp and insert to the animated list. How do I remove the 10th element from AnimatedList widget if it got removed from local list by comparison. Can I implement this in a better, efficient way?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a list diff will help.  You can either code one from scratch, or perhaps use this existing one: https://pub.dev/packages/list_diff.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28157077)

Comment: If the link ever changes, the advice is no good anyway. :)

Comment: Advice solves some parts of problems but creates other problems also. I will try to use logic of the package since it serves for my purpose, partly. If I find solution myself I will post here.